# Resizing Bitmap Files Partially Working - Enlarge Works but Reducing Doesn't

Tags: c, image, image-resizing, cs50

I've written a program that resizes a bitmap by a factor between 0-100 (values under 1 shrinks the image). The program works to enlarge files but it doesn't work reducing them.

I think I might be using fseek incorrectly to skip the pixels and rows.

I appreciate any time you commit to reviewing this problem.

Please note the code is ugly because I'm just learning to code. Any recommendations are welcome but may cause additional confusion so please explain your answer to a 5 year old.

You can run the program using a command similar to "./resize .5 large.bmp test.bmp"

Both program files are attached resize.c and bmp.h

I've also attached the before and after images to get a better idea of the problem.

after:
[image: after]

before:
[image: before]

```
// Copies a BMP file

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "bmp.h"

int zoom(float number, int biwidth);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: copy infile outfile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // remember filenames
    char* a = NULL;
    float num0 = strtof(argv[1], &a);
    int num = ceil(num0);
    char *infile = argv[2];
    char *outfile = argv[3];

    if (num0 < 0 || num0 > 100)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Resize only 0-100. Try again.\n");
        return 5;
    }

    // open input file
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "rb");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 2;
    }

    // open output file
    FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "wb");
    if (outptr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
        return 3;
    }

    // read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
    if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
        bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
    {
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file format.\n");
        return 4;
    }

    // calculate old padding
    int padding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;
    printf("padding%i ", padding);

    //create new header files to save to
    BITMAPINFOHEADER newbi = bi;
    BITMAPFILEHEADER newbf = bf;

    //determine width and set minimum size
    int biwidth = round(bi.biWidth * num0);
    if (biwidth < 3)
    {
        newbi.biWidth = 3;
    }
    else
    {
        newbi.biWidth = biwidth;

    }
    printf("newbiwidth%i ", newbi.biWidth);

    //determine height and set minimum size
    int biheight = round(bi.biHeight) * num0;
    if (biheight > -3)
    {
        newbi.biHeight = -3;
    }
    else
    {
        newbi.biHeight = biheight;

    }
    printf("newbiheight%i ", newbi.biHeight);

    // determine new padding for scanlines
    int newpadding = (4 - (newbi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;
    printf("newpadding%i ", newpadding);

    //determine new image size
    newbi.biSizeImage = (newbi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) + newpadding) * abs(newbi.biHeight);
    printf("newbisizeimage%i ", newbi.biSizeImage);

    //determine new file size
    newbf.bfSize = newbi.biSizeImage + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    printf("newbfsize%i ", newbf.bfSize);

    // write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    fwrite(&newbf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    fwrite(&newbi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);


    // temporary storage

    int factor = zoom(num0, bi.biWidth);
    RGBTRIPLE triple;
    RGBTRIPLE *triple1 = malloc(sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) * factor);
    RGBTRIPLE *sline = malloc(newbi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));

    //determine whether to loop old or new width
    int biheight1 = 0;
    int biwidth1= 0;
    if ( bi.biWidth > newbi.biWidth)
    biwidth1 = newbi.biWidth;
    else
    biwidth1 = bi.biWidth;

    //determine whether to loop old or new height
    if ( abs(bi.biHeight) > abs(newbi.biHeight))
    biheight1 = abs(newbi.biHeight);
    else
    biheight1 = abs(bi.biHeight);

    // read RGB triple from infile based on shrink or enlarge
    for (int i = 0; i < biheight1; i++)
    {
        printf("H%i  ", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < biwidth1; j++)
        {
            printf("W%i  ", j);

            if (num0 > .5 && num0 < 1)
            fread(triple1, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), factor, inptr);
            else
            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

            //store new triple as new scanline

            for (int m = 0; m < num ; m++)
            {
                if (num0 <= .5)
                {
                    sline[j] = triple;
                }
                else if (num0 > .5 && num0 < 1)
                {
                    sline[j] = *triple1;
                }
                else
                {
                    sline[j * num + m] = triple;
                }
                printf("T%i,J%i  ", m, j);
            }

            //skip pixel(s) if image is shrinking
            for (int n = 0; n < num ; n++)
            {
                if (num0 > .5 && num0 < 1)
                {
                    fseek(inptr, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), SEEK_CUR);
                }
                else if (num0 <= .5)
                {
                        fseek(inptr, (sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) * factor), SEEK_CUR);
                }
            }
        }
        // skip over padding, if any
        fseek(inptr,padding, SEEK_CUR);

        //write new scanline to file
        for (int k = 0; k < num; k++)
        {
            printf("F%i  ", k);
            fwrite(sline, (newbi.biWidth * 3), 1, outptr);

            // add padding if any
            for (int h = 0; h < newpadding; h++)
            {
                fputc(0x00, outptr);
            }
        }

            //skip scanline(s) if shrinking
            for (int o = 0; o < num ; o++)
            {
                if (num0 > .5 && num0 < 1)
                {
                    fseek(inptr, (bi.biWidth + padding), SEEK_CUR);
                }
                else if (num0 <= .5)
                {
                    fseek(inptr, ((bi.biWidth + padding) * factor), SEEK_CUR);
                }
            }

    }

    //free memory
    free(sline);
    free(triple1);


    // close infile
    fclose(inptr);

    // close outfile
    fclose(outptr);


    // success
    return 0;
}


//determine shrink factor
int zoom(float number, int biwidth)
{

    int zoom1;
    int a;
    int b;
    a = (biwidth * number);
    b = (biwidth - a);
    if ( a > b && b != 0)
    {
        zoom1 = a/b;
    }
    else if (a < b && a != 0)
    {
        zoom1 = b/a;
    }
    else if (b <= 0)
    {
        zoom1 = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        zoom1 = 1;
    }
    return zoom1;
}


    // BMP-related data types based on Microsoft's own

#include <stdint.h>

// aliases for C/C++ primitive data types
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230309.aspx

typedef uint8_t  BYTE;
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
typedef int32_t  LONG;
typedef uint16_t WORD;

// information about the type, size, and layout of a file
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374(v=vs.85).aspx
typedef struct
{
    WORD bfType;
    DWORD bfSize;
    WORD bfReserved1;
    WORD bfReserved2;
    DWORD bfOffBits;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
BITMAPFILEHEADER;

// information about the dimensions and color format
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx
typedef struct
{
    DWORD biSize;
    LONG biWidth;
    LONG biHeight;
    WORD biPlanes;
    WORD biBitCount;
    DWORD biCompression;
    DWORD biSizeImage;
    LONG biXPelsPerMeter;
    LONG biYPelsPerMeter;
    DWORD biClrUsed;
    DWORD biClrImportant;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
BITMAPINFOHEADER;

// relative intensities of red, green, and blue
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162939(v=vs.85).aspx
typedef struct
{
    BYTE rgbtBlue;
    BYTE rgbtGreen;
    BYTE rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

Comment: Just a quick look: When you do `fseek` in many places you multiply by `sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)` but when you skip scanlines, you don't. Do you want (e.g.) `fseek(inptr, (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) + padding), SEEK_CUR);` instead of `fseek(inptr, (bi.biWidth + padding), SEEK_CUR);`?

Comment: @CraigEsteyThanks! I looked at this all day and didn't spot it. That seems to be the main problem.

Comment: Sam or @CraigEstey, one of you please make an answer, in order to get this out of the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution was posted by @CraigEstey:

fseek for skipping scanlines was incomplete. The bi.biWidth needs to be multiplied by the sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)

Use fseek(inptr, ((bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) + padding), SEEK_CUR); instead of fseek(inptr, (bi.biWidth + padding), SEEK_CUR);

The program now works for both enlarging and shrinking images with this fix.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{

    struct rgb { unsigned char r, g, b; };

    float scale = 1.5;//0 to 100!

    // open input and output file
    FILE* inptr  = fopen("in.bmp", "rb");
    FILE* outptr = fopen("out.bmp","wb");

    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);


    // calculate old padding
    int pad = (4 - (bi.biWidth * 3) % 4) % 4;

    //create new header files
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi2 = bi;
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf2 = bf;

    //image old
    int width = bi.biWidth;
    int height = bi.biHeight;

    //image new
    int width2 = ceil(bi.biWidth * scale);
    int height2 = ceil(bi.biHeight *scale);  

    //new header
    bi2.biWidth = width2;
    bi2.biHeight = height2;
    int pad2 = (4 - (width2 * 3) % 4) % 4;
    bi2.biSizeImage = (width2 * 3 + pad2) * height2;
    bf2.bfSize = bi2.biSizeImage + 54;        


    //header save
    fwrite(&bf2, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);
    fwrite(&bi2, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);


    rgb *p  = (rgb*)malloc(width*height* sizeof(rgb));   //image old
    rgb *p2 = (rgb*)malloc(width2*height2* sizeof(rgb));  //image2 new


    //write p
    int say = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {

            fread(p + say, 3, 1, inptr);
            say++;
        }
        fseek(inptr, pad, SEEK_CUR);
    }

    //write p---->p2
    int say2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width2; j++)
        {
            int x = j / scale ;
            int y = i / scale ;
            int say = y * width + x;

            memcpy(p2+say2, p + say, sizeof(rgb));
            say2++;
        }
    }

    //write file
    say = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width2; j++)
        {
            fwrite(p2+say, sizeof(rgb), 1, outptr);
            say++;
        }
        for (int h = 0; h < pad2; h++)
                fputc(0x00, outptr);
    }



    fclose(inptr);
    fclose(outptr);


    return 0;
}
```